# How to send responses from onMessageExternal Listener?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am sending a message from a content script to my extension using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.

**Content Script:**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, {
        "some" : "request"
        }
    },
    function(response) {
        alert("got response");
    }
);
```

The receiving part in the background script looks like that:

**Background Script A**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("send response");
    sendResponse({
        "some" : "response"
    });
});
```

This works well: `send response` is logged to the console of the background page and I receive the alert `got response` from the content script.

I then introduced some asynchronous JavaScript to the listener:

**Background Script B**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({
        name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
        modulusLength: 2048,
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
        hash: {
            name: "SHA-256"
        }
    }, false, ["sign"]).then(function(keyPair) {
        console.log("send response");
        sendResponse({
            "some" : "response"
        });
    });
});
```

here the callback is called regularly (meaning, `send response` is logged to the console of the background page after completion. The content script however never receives the response (i.e. there is no `got response` alert).

What am I doing wrong here? Why is the `responseCallback` called in A but not in B? That's exactly what the callback chain is made for or isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=343007)/[feature](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessageExternal) in chrome. Apparently you need to return `true`, otherwise the message channel will be closed:

> *https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessageExternal*
>
> This function becomes invalid when the event listener returns, unless you return true from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to the other end until sendResponse is called).

Adding `return true;` to the background script like this solves the issue:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({
        name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
        modulusLength: 2048,
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
        hash: {
            name: "SHA-256"
        }
    }, false, ["sign"]).then(function(keyPair) {
        console.log("send response");
        sendResponse({
            "some" : "response"
        });
    });
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Does the listener function send back `{some: "response"}` to the sender or just `true`?